# pandas indexing to multiindex data

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataset where

```
df.columns=MultiIndex(levels=[['Area\n (In sq. km)', 'District Code', 'India/ State/ Union Territory/ District/ Sub-district', 'Name', 'Number of households', 'Number of towns', 'Number of villages', 'Population', 'Population per sq. km.', 'Sub District Code', 'Total/\nRural/\nUrban', 'index'], ['Females', 'Inhabited', 'Males', 'Persons', 'Uninhabited', 'Unnamed: 0_level_2', 'Unnamed: 12_level_2', 'Unnamed: 13_level_2', 'Unnamed: 1_level_2', 'Unnamed: 2_level_2', 'Unnamed: 3_level_2', 'Unnamed: 4_level_2', 'Unnamed: 7_level_2', 'Unnamed: 8_level_2', ''], [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, '']],
       labels=[[11, 1, 9, 2, 3, 10, 6, 6, 5, 4, 7, 7, 7, 0, 8], [14, 5, 8, 9, 10, 11, 1, 4, 12, 13, 3, 2, 0, 6, 7], [13, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 11, 12]],
       names=['State  Code', None, 1])
```

Now, when i want to do some operation where 'Total/\nRural/\nUrban' is 'Total' as in below:
df.loc[df.index.get_level_values('Total/\nRural/\nUrban')=="Total"]

I am getting "ValueError: Cannot index with multidimensional key".

Even df=df.reset_index() doesn't help.
I have been trying a lot, couldn't find any way. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks a lot,
Sudip

Comment: Can you create a small dataframe with the dataset and show what is expected.